# Unable to access ftp through cli (linux), while through file browser, works perfect

Tags: linux-networking, ftp

I am trying to download a file from a ftp server (an Insight debugger release, from it's official web (https://sourceware.org/insight/downloads.php)).
The ftp url is: ftp://sourceware.org/pub/insight/releases

If I click it in the browser on my linux (or in my Mac), it just asks for permission to open Dolphin or Finder and after choosing "guest", shows the contents as if it was a normal local folder on my computer.

The thing is that I want to do it from command line, using the `ftp` command.
When I try, this happens:

```
$ ftp ftp://sourceware.org/pub/insight/releases
Connected to sourceware.org.
220 Welcome to sourceware FTP service.
331 Please specify the password.
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
200 Switching to Binary mode.
250 Directory successfully changed.
250 Directory successfully changed.
local: releases remote: releases
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||36594|)
550 Failed to open file.
221 Goodbye.
                                                                              
$
```

Comment: Can you try with wget `wget --user=NAME --password='PASSWORD' ftp://url/path/file.name`

Comment: @Turdie I just would like to start an `ftp` session so I can navigate through the directories and chose anything at will. I'm afraid if I use `wget` in that fashion, what will happen is that I will download the whole directory with all its subdirectories (all the releases in this case)? I want to start the `ftp` session, just that. (The posted ftp url is not about a precise file, is a folder that contains many releases).

Comment: Keep in mind that directory listing could be disabled. In most ftp servers you can grant or deny that privilege. Are you able to try with Filezilla a GUI FTP client if you then can do a directory listing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the issue here is that your command line client, seeing the path that you're passing in, believes that you're asking for the file "releases"; the response sequence you're showing does reflect trying to retrieve a file, rather than a directory. What happens if you try

```
ftp ftp://sourceware.org
cd /pub/insight/releases
```

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly. How if you would like to include the (blank) password in the url? Because, this logs in, but asks for password: `ftp anonymous@sourceware.org` and this as well `ftp -a sourceware.org` does the whole thing. I tried this (nothing after the colon): `ftp anonymous:@sourceware.org`, but doesn't work.

Comment: I have never tried anonymous FTP from the command line, the FTP servers I use from the command line require passwords. But from the man pages it looks like you should be able to do this with `ftp anonymous:""@sourceware.org`, if you're not happy with the `-a` option.

Comment: The man page also suggests that `ftp ftp://sourceware.org/pub/insight/releases/` (note the trailing slash) would drop you into the directory, rather than trying to download the directory as if it was a file.